# Finding whether C is a proper subset of B

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let A = {1, 2, 3}, B = the power set of A = P(A), and C = {1, {1}}.

Is C a proper subset of B?

*** EDIT ***
B = 1, 2, 3

Comment: Do you have any work so far?

Comment: What are the kind of elements that $B$ contains? What are the kind of elements that $C$ contains? Are $1$ and $\{ 1\}$ the same type of element?

Comment: **Hint** Write out what B is.

Comment: Ok, I wrote it out

Comment: No.  B is not 1,2,3, or even $\{ 1,2,3 \}$. Look up what a power set is and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P(A)=B={{1},{2},{3},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{1,2,3},{}}

So C is not a proper subset of B.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an $x \in C$ such that $x \notin P(A)=B$, then $C$ is not a subset of $B$. Since $P(A)$ contains no integers, and $1 \in C$, the answer is no.